# How to show custom error message when there is not internet

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

After entering some values, when the user disconnects the internet and tries to perform any action. My application is not showing any error message stating "There is no internet connection"
In console it is throwing

angular_1.3.13.js:11613 TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null
    at Object.handleError (apiHelper.js:120)
    at shortnoteCreateController.js:88
    at angular_1.3.13.js:9382
    at processQueue (angular_1.3.13.js:13195)
    at angular_1.3.13.js:13211
    at Scope.$eval (angular_1.3.13.js:14407)
    at Scope.$digest (angular_1.3.13.js:14223)
    at Scope.$apply (angular_1.3.13.js:14512)
    at done (angular_1.3.13.js:9665)
    at completeRequest (angular_1.3.13.js:9855)

Handled error in below code.

this.handleError = function(status, data) {

```
        if (status == URLs.unauthorizedCode && address.location.hash != "#/login") {
            var userdet = this.getUserDetailsFromServer(URLs.HTTP_GET, URLs.requestheaders);
            userdet.success(function(data) {
                //navigate to login page when unauthorized operations performed
                //its a rare case of getting permission reverted by PA when in action
                //or if logged out in another tab or logged in as another user in another tab
                //localStorageService.set('successmsg', 'You have been prevented from an unauthorized access');
                 displayResult.showErrorResults(Constants.authorizationFailureMsg,'success');
                address.location.href = URLs.loginView;
                //address.location.reload();
                //console.info("in handle error auth fail");

            });
            userdet.error(function(data) {
                localStorageService.set('successmsg', 'You have been prevented from an unauthorized access');

                localStorageService.clearAll();
                address.location.href = URLs.loginView;
                address.location.reload();
                displayResult.showErrorResults(Constants.authorizationFailureMsg,'success');
                //console.info("in handle error auth fail");

            });
        } else if(status == URLs.notFoundCode){
            address.location.href = URLs.notFoundPage;
        }else {

            $rootScope.rs_error_status = status;
            //console.log("inside apihelper", data);
            if (data.error) {
                $rootScope.rs_error_data = data;
                //console.info("in error");
            } else if (data.errors) {
                //console.info("in errors");
                $rootScope.rs_error_data = data.errors;
            }
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl : 'userinterface/pages/modal/errordialog.html',
                controller : 'modalController'
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                //console.info("Exiting modal popup");
            }, function() {
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) which returns boolean true/false for online and offline

Also you can attach `online/offline` event to the window

```
window.addEventListener('offline', (e)=> { //code here});

window.addEventListener('online', (e) => { //some code here});
```